# Using the input of a user to search for a specific row in a excel file (python)

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am currently making a program that checks what user is logged onto a computer and then will perform different actions depending on who is logged in. for this is have been using "getpass" and have done that successfully and the user name is saved to a variable named "who". This is where I have found an issue, I want to be able to be able to search an excel file for the name in the variable and only print the row that it is in. How can I do this?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Here we don't just write code, we help you solve problems, so I strongly advise reading  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then providing some actual issue you are running into

Answer (score 1):

Can you get the Excel file saved in a CSV format?  If so, you can use Python's csv module to parse the file.

Let's assume that you can get the file saved in CSV format, named directory.csv, and it looks like this:

```
first,last,login,phone
Chi,Kaso,ckaso,999-999-9999
Bob,McCormick,bobmac,888-888-8888
Mason,Builder,mbuilder,777-777-7777
```

Here is code that will open the file, read each line with csv.reader, and find the matching line:

```
import csv
user = 'mbuilder'
with open('directory.csv', mode='r', newline='') as dir_file:
    reader = csv.reader(dir_file)
    for row in reader:
            if row[2] == user:
                    print("Match:", row)
                    break
```

The downside is that it searches the file row-by-row, so if the file had millions of users, it would be slow.

Comment: Thank you very much this has been a big help